# How to send picture to browser in Java

Tags: java, arrays, server, client, byte

I may be on the wrong path all together.  I'm trying to send a .gif or .jpg file to my FireFox browser using server code I wrote in Java.

With this code:

```
  File pic = new File(pictureFile);
  byte[] byteContent = Files.readAllBytes(pic.toPath());
  //System.out.println("Content: " + Arrays.toString(byteContent));
```

I'm sure that I successfully wrote the file into a byte array because if you uncomment the System.out.println() line there's content in my IDE that read [-1, -40, -1, -32, 0...] (and so on).

When I try to output the picture to my browser like this:

```
  os.write("<html><head><title>Not Found</title></head><body>\n".getBytes());
  os.write("<h3>" .getBytes());
  os.write( byteContent);
  os.write(" </h3>\n".getBytes());
  os.write("</body></html>\n".getBytes());
```

the output is garbage.  What do I need to do?  I'm certain that I'm sending the correct HTTP Header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image data cannot be put directly in HTML data.

You can encode the image in base64 and put it in HTML code in this way:

```
<img src="data:(file type);base64,(base64 text)">
```

The `file type` should be `image/gif` for .gif and `image/jpeg` for .jpg

example:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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">
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using a package you have to add to your path?   Am I far off from sending a picture in binary mode?  I'd rather do it that way if possible.

Comment: How about giving up to send the HTML and sending only the image data (with appropriate HTTP header)?

Comment: Like I said I'm lost.  I don't know the best method.  How do I do that Mike?

Comment: First of all, what do you want to do? What is important for you? Sending image without encoding? Setting the title on browsers to "Not Found"? Other?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly display byte content into the browser. Use the following steps

**Step 1 : Convert the Byte array to data url**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("data:image/png;base64,");
sb.append(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(byteContent, false)));
String newImage = sb.toString();
```

**Step 2 : Use this inside img tag**

```
os.write("<img src="+newImage+" />");
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using a package you have to add to your path?   Am I far off from sending a picture in binary mode?  I'd rather do it that way if possible.